# MacBook Pro Mid 2009 has a recovery partition?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, recovery

Does my computer (Snow Leopard, MacBook Pro mid 2009), have a recovery hidden partition? How can I access that?

I have the DVDs that came with my laptop, but when I start my laptop, and press and hold C key, nothing happens! I hear the noise from optical drive, but it is stuck to the gray initial screen, with the circle rotating.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No Recovery Partitions came in with Lion

Comment: Try pressing the "option" Key during startup.. It should show all your drives. Let us know if it didn't worked, then pls provide a pic if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it just sits at the grey screen and the option boot or C boot doesn't work, it is 98% probable that your hard drive or hard drive cable have failed.

Time to head to your local apple store.

Comment: I have a bootcamp Win in my system and it works perfectly fine when I boot to my windows on the same laptop, but the OsX partition completely disappeared! 

It cann't be the cable for sure, right? (because it works fine in windows and shows my FAT32 and NTFS partitions).

Do you think I need to buy a new hard and substitute it? Or I just reformat it, repartition it, and use it till it dies and then I buy a new one? how long they usually last after showing this type of failure symptoms?(bad sectors?)

tnx

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your first question is no, unfortunately mid 2009 mbp's didn't have the recovery partition built in.

In regards to your dvd boot issue, you'll probably need to provide quite a bit more info for a definitive solution, but I can offer a few suggestions anyway. First off, try holding the option key when booting to see all your available discs, hopefully you'll see the inserted DVD and the problem will be solved.

If you still have no luck, try booting into verbose mode (command + v at startup) and seeing if theres any obvious system hangs. Verbose mode just basically shows you whats going on behind the scenes when you're starting up.

If you can provide a bit more info, like why you're reinstalling and if theres an OS currently loaded on the drive, hopefully we can zero in on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the DVD is bad. Can you get a copy of the install DVD put on a USB stick or drive and boot to that?